# insert a new TextView in a dialog box after pressing on a button in the dialog box

Tags: android, dialog, textview

i have a custom dialog box, it has a textview an edittext and 2 buttons. i'm trying to  create a new textview that containes the text of the edittext everytime  the user presses on the 'add' button,and locate it beneath the buttons. how can i do that?  here's what i tried:

```
ingDlgBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        //showDialog(INGS_DIALOG);

        final Dialog customIngsDlg = new Dialog(context);
        customIngsDlg.setContentView(R.layout.custom_ings_dialog);
        customIngsDlg.setTitle("Ingredients");
        TextView ingsDlgTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ingsDialogTitleTv);
        final EditText ingsEt = (EditText)customIngsDlg.findViewById(R.id.ingsDialogEt);
        final Button ingsAddBtn = (Button)customIngsDlg.findViewById(R.id.ingsAddButton);
        final Button ingsFinishBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ingsFinishButton);

        ingsAddBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // ArrayList<String> ingsTmp = new ArrayList<String>();
                String ingredient = ingsEt.getText().toString();
                ingredients.add(ingredient);
                ingsEt.setText("");
                TextView ingItemTv = new TextView(customIngsDlg.getContext());
                ingItemTv.setText(ingredient);
                RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(OwnRecipeAdding.this);
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parms = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                parms.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,ingsEt.getId());
                layout.setLayoutParams(parms);
                customIngsDlg.addContentView(ingItemTv,parms);

            }
        });

        //  ingsFinishBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        //
        //      @Override
        //      public void onClick(View v) {
        //
        //          customIngsDlg.dismiss();
        //      }
        //  });

        customIngsDlg.show();
    }
});
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding the text view to your custom layout in the .xml file and then add text to that when the add button is pressed.

This needs a bit of styling, but it's functional.  You'll likely need a scroll view in there when the list becomes too long.

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/dialog_fragment_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_textview_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:text="Add Ingredients" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/dialog_edittext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/button_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_add"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_finish"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Finish" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_textview_2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:text="" />

</LinearLayout>
```

DialogFragment class:

```
public class TestDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

   private Button buttonAdd;
   private Button buttonFinish;
   private TextView addTextView;
   private EditText editText;

   public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
      View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_fragment, null);

      buttonAdd = (Button)dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.button_add);
      buttonFinish = (Button)dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.button_finish);
      editText = (EditText)dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.dialog_edittext);
      addTextView = (TextView)dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.dialog_textview_2);

      buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String text = addTextView.getText().toString();
            text = text + "\n" + editText.getText().toString();
            addTextView.setText(text);
            editText.setText("");
        }

      });

      AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
      builder.setView(dialoglayout)
             .setTitle("Ingredients")
             .setCancelable(false)
             .setInverseBackgroundForced(true);

      AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

      return dialog;
       }


}
```

Comment: Thanks  for  the answer ,but i want to do something that is not limited, I  mean not one textview but as many as the user needs to insert.

Comment: So, you want to add a new TextView for every new item that the user adds?  May I ask why?  It is adding complexity that you probably don't need.